# How to use form_for in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, form-for

I would like to send an email to the user with a form inside:

I tried the following

`booking_confirmation.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@event, :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field(:customer_id, :value => nil) %>
<%= f.submit "Cancel", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
<% end %>
```

But then I have to set up `protect_against_forgery` to `false` in a UserMailerHelper which breaks weirdly my login action...

Is there no simplier way to just send a PUT request to my `event_url` with one parameter `:customer_id`?

Thank you for your help!

I tried the following as well. It does not work, does anyone see why and could help me pass through it?

```
<%= link_to "Cancel", url_for(controller: 'events', action: 'update', only_path: false, :customer_id => "0"), :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you useing the form of form_for,just replaced it by the form of a link with parameter(s).

```
    <%= link_to "Cancel", url_for(:action => event_url, :customer_id => @event.customer_id), :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried that but then I receive the following error : `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}`. I think there is a need to specify the action but I do not know how

Comment: what's your route.rb config?